# ASP.NET ListView Elements Display <#Eval?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, data-binding

I've got a ListView control that uses a custom data source. It will be a database soon, but for now I am still trying to get it running.

In the HTML of my form, I have the following code:

```
<%-- Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.layouttemplate.aspx --%>
<asp:ListView ID="lvOfficers" runat="server"
    OnSelectedIndexChanging="lvOfficers_SelectedIndexChanging"
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="lvOfficers_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table id="tblOfficers">
            <tr>
                <th style="width:20%"></th>
                <th colspan="2">Member Name</th>
                <th style="width:20%"></th>
                <th style="width:20%"></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Last</th>
                <th>First</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td><asp:Label ID="lblRank" runat="server" Text='<#Eval("Rank") %>'></asp:Label></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="lblLast" runat="server" Text='<#Eval("LastName") %>'></asp:Label></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="lblFirst" runat="server" Text='<#Eval("FirstName") %>'></asp:Label></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="lblPhone" runat="server" Text='<#Eval("HomePhone") %>'></asp:Label></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="lblEmail1" runat="server" Text='<#Eval("PersonalEmail") %>'></asp:Label></td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

In the code behind with the **Page_Load**, I populate the data:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (!IsPostBack) {
      GetOfficers();
  }
}

protected void GetOfficers() {
    lvOfficers.DataSource = Personnel.GetOfficers();
    lvOfficers.DataBind();
}
```

I can step through in Debug mode and see that there are 8 elements of type **Person** in a ListView that my "GetOfficers" data factory churns out.

The **Person** class contains subclasses:

- **Phone** class: for {`Home`, `Cell`, `Work`},
- **Address** class {`Primary`, `Secondary`} that contain ranking logic to indicate contact methods, and
- **Membership** class. One tracks a member's `ID`, `JoinDate`, and `Expiration` while a second instance tracks the same elements for **LifeMembership**.

Thinking this complex **Person** class was causing my problems, I edited the **GetOfficers()** method to use an anonymous list:

```
protected void GetOfficers() {
    var officers = Personnel.GetOfficers();
    var data = from o in officers
                select new {
                    o.Rank,
                    o.LastName,
                    o.FirstName,
                    o.HomePhone,
                    o.PersonalEmail,
                };
    //var data = (from o in officers
    //            select new {
    //                o.Rank,
    //                o.LastName,
    //                o.FirstName,
    //                o.HomePhone,
    //                o.PersonalEmail,
    //            }).OrderBy(o => o.Rank).OrderBy(o => o.LastName);
    lvOfficers.DataSource = data;
    lvOfficers.DataBind();
}
```

I was pretty sure that was going to solve my problems at first, so I included the two **OrderBy** clauses. When it did not work, I commented it out to try again, but I still got no success.

No matter what I seem to try, the page displays with the "Eval" text showing instead of the actual data.

[image: screenshot]

I'm guessing the answer is something simple that I am overlooking because I use this same technique to populate the data in other pages in the same project.

### How do I get my data to show up?

Comment: `Text='<#Eval("Rank") %>'` should be `Text='<%#Eval("Rank") %>'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `%` at the start like this:-

```
'<%# Eval("Rank") %>'
```

Comment: Beautiful! I knew it had to be something simple. I generally write for Windows Forms, so I make silly mistakes when I try doing Web. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome :) ASP.NET Code nuggets just requires extra care ;)

Answer (score 2):

you need to add % sign at the start of eval

'<%#Eval("FieldName")%>'